# How to get the posts whose custom date is between 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-31?

Tags: wordpress

I have added new posts with the custom date and now i want to get all those posts whose custom date is between 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-31.
I am trying following code but it is not returning me any data.

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'post_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(array(
                'key' => 'post_date',
                'value' => array(2016 - 01 - 01, 2016 - 01 - 31),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'date',
            ),
        ),
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) :
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    the_title();
   endwhile;
```

Comment: You should surround the dates with `'` or `"` and remove the white spaces between numbers and `- `, the way it is php is is passing the result of a subtraction. Is your custom field named `post_date` like the default field?

Comment: @ Felipe Elia i have tried both ' and " but still i am unable to get the data.

Comment: @Felipe Elia, oh yes  thanks i have got the data. Thanks a lot bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query:

Return posts from January 1st to February 28th

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2013',
            'before'    => array(
                'year'  => 2013,
                'month' => 2,
                'day'   => 28,
            ),
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

One more solution:

```
$args = array(
    'year'     => 2016,
    'monthnum' => 1,
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Or go through below URL which contains lots of other examples, matching with your requirements.

**Reference URL:** https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52070/how-to-get-posts-published-between-a-date-and-today